# Functional derivatives of Fourier transform

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I've tried to calculate this as well as been looking around online and I can't seem to find the calculation of this.   If $\mathfrak{F}$ is the Fourier transform:
$$
f\mapsto \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{ix}dx,
$$
then what would the functional derivative
$$
\frac{\delta \mathfrak{F}}{\delta f}
$$
be?

Comment: The Fourier transform is a linear operator so the derivative is?

Comment: It is itself, if I'm correct?

Comment: Yoh are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional derivative is defined as the linear mapping 
$$\left\langle \frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)} F[f](\xi), \phi(x) \right\rangle := \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} F[f+\lambda\phi](\xi) \right|_{\lambda=0}$$

For $\mathfrak F[f](\xi) := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)e^{ix\xi} \, dx$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (f+\lambda\phi)(x)e^{ix\xi} \, dx \right|_{\lambda=0}
& = \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(f(x)+\lambda\phi(x)\right)e^{ix\xi} \, dx \right|_{\lambda=0} \\
& = \left. \frac{d}{d\lambda} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{ix\xi} \, dx + \lambda \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) e^{ix\xi} \, dx \right) \right|_{\lambda=0} \\
& = \left. \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) e^{ix\xi} \, dx \right|_{\lambda=0} \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) e^{ix\xi} \, dx \\
& = \left\langle e^{ix\xi}, \phi(x) \right\rangle
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta f(x)} \mathfrak F[f](\xi) = e^{ix\xi}$$

Comment: This answer uses a wrong definition of the Fourier transform. It is an operator $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$, not a functional $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Bananach. Look at the question!

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it a Fourier transform and not just the value at $\xi=1$. I haven't taken $\mathfrak F$ to act on distributions though.

Comment: It is still incorrect as you cannot consider pointwise derivatives. But this is just a matter of rewriting and presenting your calculations in a more formal manner

Comment: I know that it is formally incorrect, but I use this notation in a similar way as one sometimes writes $u(x)$ for a distribution; it's not meant as the value at $x$ but rather to denote what variable belongs to $u$. An example of such notation: $\langle u * v, \phi \rangle = \langle u(x) \otimes v(y), \phi(x+y) \rangle$.

Comment: I guess that for the OP these things are not necessarily that clear, and he probably will be better served by the understanding of the derivative as simply a map from $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In this setting, it doesn't make sense to have $\exp(ix\xi)$ as a derivative of $\mathcal{F}[f](\xi)$ (i.e. with fixed wave number) since it is no element of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. In any case, any calculation to find the derivative of a linear operator is obfuscating

Comment: But $\mathfrak F$ is not only a map $L^2(\mathbb R^n) \to L^2(\mathbb R^n)$. It's also a map $L^1(\mathbb R^n) \to BC(\mathbb R^n)$, the bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$. Both $L^1$ and $BC$ containt $\exp(ix\xi)$.

Comment: $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ doesn't

Comment: You're right. Don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking for derivative of Fourier transform ?

considering $\omega$ insted of $f$ we can write accroding to the definition

> $$\begin{align}\frac{d \mathcal{F}(\omega)}{d\omega}&=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)\frac{d}{d\omega}\cdot e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\&=-i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}t.f(t)e^{i\omega t}\,dt\\&=-i \cdot\mathcal{IFT}\{t \,.f(t)\}\end{align}$$

And the reverse process can be

> $$\mathcal{FT}\left\{\frac{d f^n(t)}{d^nt}\right\}=(i\omega)^n.F(\omega)$$

Please let me know if somehow i can improve my answer , Thanks !

Comment: Quick question, what are $\mathfrak{I},msthfrak{T}$ symbolise?

Comment: @CSA sorry i'm not very much adept with latex formatting i'm just learning those , the first one seems to be for imaginary part , i don't know about others

Comment: He was asking for the functional derivative of the Fourier transform, not the derivative of the Fourier transform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative

Comment: sorry for wrong answer , i'm new to integral transforms and couldn't interpret his query correctly , sorry for that @md2perpe

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light. No problem. It's easy to misunderstand a question.